# How to determine if arbitrary point lies inside or outside a conic

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Given the general equation of a conic 
$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0 $, is there a way to determine if an arbitrary point $(x_1,y_1)$ lies inside or outside of the conic (ex. parabola or ellipse)?

Comment: You might need to clarify what "inside or outside" means, for a parabola / straight line / pair of straight lines.

Comment: By 'inside' I had meant the part containing the foci for conic sections like parabola/hyberbola/ellipse. I guess it cannot be defined for straight lines.

Comment: You seem to want the points closer to the focus than the points on the conic. This is computable in terms of the focus, the directrix and the eccentricity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g(x,y) = Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F$.  I think the condition you want is that $(x_1,y_1)$ is "inside" the conic if and only if
$$ g(x_1,y_1) \quad\text{has the same sign as}\quad
\left|\begin{matrix}
2A & B & D \\
B & 2C & E \\
D & E & 2F
\end{matrix}\right| $$
(If that determinant is zero, the conic is degenerate — see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387177) — so the idea of "inside" doesn't make sense.)  This works for ellipses and hyperbolas at least, and I think it works for parabolas too, though I don't see how to prove it now.

The idea is that the conic $g(x,y)=0$ divides the plane into two regions $g(x,y)<0$ and $g(x,y)>0$, one of them being "inside" and the other "outside"; to find out which is which, test the centre $(x_c,y_c)$ of the conic (which is inside if it's an ellipse and outside if it's a hyperbola).  It turns out that
$$ \left|\begin{matrix}
2A & B & D \\
B & 2C & E \\
D & E & 2F
\end{matrix}\right|
= 2g(x_c,y_c)
\left|\begin{matrix}
2A & B \\
B & 2C
\end{matrix}\right|
\tag{$\ast$} $$
The determinant on the RHS is the (negative of the) discriminant of the conic; if the conic is an ellipse, that determinant is positive, so $g(x_c,y_c)$ and the determinant on the LHS have the same sign (which is what we want, because the centre is inside), whereas if the conic is a hyperbola then the determinant on the RHS is negative, so $g(x_c,y_c)$ and the determinant on the LHS have opposite signs (which is what we want, because the centre is outside).

To show ($\ast$), use the fact that $\nabla g(x_c,y_c)=0$; since
$$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y) = 2Ax+By+D
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y) = Bx+2Cy+E
\text{ ,} $$
we get that
$$ \left[\begin{matrix} 2A & B & D \\ B & 2C & E \end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix} x_c \\ y_c \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right]
= \left[\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right] $$
and so
$$ g(x_c,y_c) = \frac12
\left[\begin{matrix} x_c & y_c & 1 \end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
2A & B & D \\
B & 2C & E \\
D & E & 2F
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix} x_c \\ y_c \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right]
= \frac12 (Dx_c+Ey_c+2F) $$
whence
$$ \left|\begin{matrix}
2A & B & D \\
B & 2C & E \\
D & E & 2F
\end{matrix}\right|
= \det\left(
\left[\begin{matrix}
2A & B & D \\
B & 2C & E \\
D & E & 2F
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & x_c \\
0 & 1 & y_c \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right]\right)
= \left|\begin{matrix}
2A & B & 0 \\
B & 2C & 0 \\
D & E & 2g(x_c,y_c)
\end{matrix}\right|
$$
which gives ($\ast$).

Comment: In Dowling/Turneaure _Analytic Geometry_ (1914) on p. 129, I read: _A point is **outside** a conic when two tangents can be drawn from the point to the conic. A point is **inside** a conic when no tangents etc._ It could be interesting to verify analytically the relation with your exposition.