# Parametrization of an arbitrary conic

Tags: conic-sections

Let's say we have a conic of the form

$$ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey + f = 0$$

How can I parameterize it? For ellipses there is a [great answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2616866/parametrization-of-an-arbitrary-conic-ellipse). But how can I extend it for parabolas and hyperbolas as well? I understand I will need different parametric functions and also ranges.

Comment: Have you heard about the polar equation when center is one of its foci:  $r=\frac{r_0}{1+e \cos(\theta-\theta_0)}$ common to all conics with $e$ the eccentricity ($0<e<1$ for an ellipse, $e=1$ for a parabola, $e>1$ for a hyperbola) ? It is one of the simplest representations.

Comment: I've never heard about that. But it's not on parametric form, e.g. x(t) = ..., y(t) = ...

Comment: There are many different ways to describe a curve : implicit $f(x,y)=0$, explicit $y=f(x)$, parametric $x(t),y(t)$, polar $r=r(\theta)$, etc... I am surprized you haven't yet encountered the last one which is very important and provides for curves like conic curves an especially easy unified treatment.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of parametrization in [Parametrization of an arbitrary conic/ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2616866/parametrization-of-an-arbitrary-conic-ellipse) can be further extended with a general, complex parameters. For example, the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ can be parametrized with $x=a\cos t$ and $y=b\sin t$. Very similarly, for the hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, we can have $x=a\cos it$ and $y=bi\sin it$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

**P.S.**

Through a combination of transportation and rotation, the general conic curve $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$ can be converted to
$$
{
Ax^2+By^2=C\quad,\quad \text{if $b^2-4ac\ne0$}
\\
Ax^2+By=C\quad,\quad \text{if $b^2-4ac=0$}
}
$$

Comment: Ah, yes. I know it's possible. The question is how does the parameters of the hyperbolas, etc related to the original coefficients $a, b, c, d, e, f$?